# Add yticks to marginals in Seaborn JointGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

There doesn't seem to be any examples in the documentation for [`JointGrid`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) or [`JointPlot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot) that show `yticks` in the marginal plots. How can I add `yticks` to the marginal plots in the `seaborn` `JointGrid` plot below?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.JointGrid(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color='#334f6d')
g = g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, color='#418470')
```

[image]

I know what the yticks are from `g.ax_marg_x.get_yticks()`, but setting them with

```
g.ax_marg_x.set_yticks(g.ax_marg_x.get_yticks())
```

doesn't seem to do anything, nor do other simple attempts like `g.ax_marg_x.yaxis.set_visible(True)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plots something, but i'm not sure how to interpret these results (or how they were calculated; the right one does not look like a density).

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

    g = sns.JointGrid(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips)
    g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color='#334f6d')
    g = g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, color='#418470', )

    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

The relevant part to reverse-engineer is in seaborn's sources @ seaborn/axisgrid.py ([link](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0f79211cd8d25bddecbf5a6a024f0f606e8685e2/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1623)):

```
# LINE 1623 #
# Set up the subplot grid
f = plt.figure(figsize=(size, size))
gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1)

ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1], sharex=ax_joint)
ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1], sharey=ax_joint)

self.fig = f
self.ax_joint = ax_joint
self.ax_marg_x = ax_marg_x
self.ax_marg_y = ax_marg_y

# Turn off tick visibility for the measure axis on the marginal plots
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

# Turn off the ticks on the density axis for the marginal plots
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
ax_marg_x.yaxis.grid(False)
ax_marg_y.xaxis.grid(False)
```

Comment: Thanks especially for pointing me to the right location in the source.